# Problemas con filas y columnas de Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap

¿Por que razón si es que estoy colocando mas filas y columnas en la parte derecha del panel que tengo ahí no me respeta dichas filas y columnas y me pone todo en una sola linea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos los elementos que pongo independientemente de que agrege se enciman en una sola fila y en la única ocasiona que me respeta las reglas bootstrap es con las primeras filas y columnas que pongo, las siguientes causan ese error.

**Codigo**

```
<div class="container animated fadeIn">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="columna">
                Column 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="columna">
                Column 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="columna">
                Column 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 side">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Jesus</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Jesus</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="center-panel"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    /*Variables*/
    --sideBar: #2f2e41;
    --fontFocus: #36d29e;
    --fontOn: #b1b1b1;
    --shadow: 0px 0px 23px -16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    --backgroundBet: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    --secondShadow: 4px 4px 10px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    --sideShadow: 7px 2px 24px -16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    --sideBar: #2f2e41;
}

.columna {
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: var(--secondShadow);
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.side {
    margin-top: 2em;
    height: 750px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: var(--backgroundBet);
    display: flex;
    justify-items: center;
}

.center-panel {
    margin-top: 2em;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.background {
    height: 750px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: 5em;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: var(--backgroundBet);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

figure {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero no se que es lo que quieres hacer especificamente. Bootstrap tiene un orden de columnas llamadas `Cards` en donde podes utilizar `Card decks` o `Card columns`. Son muy utiles y facil de usar. No se si eso lo que estas buscando, pero espero te sirva. Te dejo el link: [card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/), saludos

Comment: Ya las habia visto pero la cuestion es que solo quiero el sistema de grid de bootstrap, no me interesan los estilos predefinidos que ya tiene ya que quiero hacer mis propios diseños

Comment: Entiendo, igualmente no entiendo porque quieres hacer a tu modo, pero bueno... mi recomendacion es que uses las clases `col-4` sin la clase `columna`, te vas a volver loco tratando de hacer algo que bootstrap ya hizo y resolvio. Tardarias menos leyendo los grid que ya define bootstrap. Pero bueno, disculpa, es solo mi recomendacion.

Comment: Qué es lo que no te está respetando? Lo único que veo que está _mal_ son las líneas que dicen "Jesus", "Jesus", que evidentemente querés que queden una debajo de la otra. Si es ese el problema, se debe a que le definiste un `display: flex` a `.side`, tendrías que agregarle `flex-direction: column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de como utilizar las columnas con `bootstrap`. Pero este solo un ejemplo y se pueden aplicar muchas mas sin la necesidad de crear o editar codigo personalizado. Todas las clases utilizadas son originarias de `bootstrap`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Prueba</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Prueba</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm bg-light">
    <p class="p-4 border bg-white">
      One of three columns
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera, seria muy raro tener errores. Pero vuelvo a decir, es solo una manera y hay muchas mas como se pueden aprender en [bootstrap grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns).

Espero esto te ayude! Abrazo!